# What's the most efficient way to filter/query a list of data?

Tags: algorithm, filtering

I have a list of objects, each of which has common integer fields like `type` and `timestamp`. That list is sorted by timestamps. I want to create a way to filter/query specific objects from that list depending on their fields. For example: select objects with `timestamp >= 100`, `timestamp <= 300` and `type == 3`.

The way I do that right now is that I loop through each element of the list and then loop through the conditions. If the object passes all of them I add it to a new list and then return it. This approach works but it's really inefficient on large lists.

I think I can improve my algorithm by replacing linear search with binary search for `timestamp`s so I can start/stop iterating through the list right from the place a condition starts/ends. But what can I do to improve the search by other non sorted fields? Should I store multiple copies of the list sorted by different fields to be able to apply binary search for every field?

I want to understand the general approach of how these things are done and how one can optimise them. (Note: I didn't provide any concrete code because I'm not interested in the language specific implementations as much as I'm interested in the general idea of how this should be done)

Comment: Databases do this all day, and whole books have been written about different approaches, what is best when, and so on. If you want to learn the theory, study that topic. Otherwise throw it into SQLite, add appropriate indexes, and call it a day.

Comment: I completely agree with btilly. "Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you plan on learning more about wheels."

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advice. I thought about using a database instead but it felt kinda wrong/inappropriate to me.

Comment: @YaroslavBiloshytskyi it is always a tradeoff, if the number of possible queries is very limited then your ideas are pretty good I think  (binary search on list or use tree). But if you don't want to limit yourself (also have to think about the future) a database is probably the best choice. It will be much easier to switch from SQLite to a "real" database than from your own little database implementation in the code.

Comment: Also if there is not too much data and you do not care that much about speed then you could just loop everything and filter, sub-optimal, but in practice sometimes good enough.